# formatting html for printing with page numbers

Tags: css, printing, html2pdf

Here’s the basic question…

I have a long HTML document (a contract with 100+ pages) that ultimately needs to be a PDF document with headers and footers (page numbers).  What is the best tool/language for making this happen?

Here’s the back story…

I work at a satellite office for a low-tech construction company that issues contracts to subcontractors, and because I am the only one who is able to unjam the printer, I have become the defacto IT person in the company.  In the past, to make a contract, someone has had to go through a MS Word document (the boiler plate contract) and type in the necessary information to produce a contract.

About a year ago, I got so frustrated with that methodology that I created a MS Access Database where a user could add information using Access forms and then a mail merge with MS Word to populate a contract.  This has been a HUGE improvement plus we have been able to start tracking money a lot more easily using the other database features.  The database is stored on a shared computer in the satellite office.  However, this system only works IF the individual users have MS Access and MS Word installed on their individual machines and only if they are physically connected to our local network.

With the success of this system at the satellite office, I am now attempting to create a web-based version of this tool that everyone in the company can use that only relies on standard software on individual machines and can be accessible anywhere.

I have converted a computer into a server for development purposes using XAMPP, created a SQL database, created HTML forms, and am using PHP to run queries.  Over the past few months, I have crash coursed my way through myriad languages including CSS, and have finally gotten everything to the point that the system will create an HTML version of the contract with everything populated.  Now I just need to format it for printing (ideally to a virtual PDF printer) with headers and footers (page numbers).  This should be the easiest part, right?

CSS with the @media: print tags would, on the surface, appear to be the best way to make this happen because CSS3 uses tags like “@top-left” and “content: counter(page)” to do everything that I want; however, after investing a lot of time setting everything up, it appears that only Foxfire kind of supports this and IE and Chrome absolutely do not.

Headers and footers overlap body content, and I can’t get the pagination to work at all.  Apparently these are common frustrations.

In my hunting, I ran across a program called Prince that would seem to do what I want (and quite a bit more), but the price tag on that is way more than I am willing to pay.

I can’t believe that what I want to do is a new or unique thing.  I suspect I am just not searching for the right keywords.  Is there a better tool/technique out there for converting HTML to a printer-friendly format without spending a ton of money?

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. But the only solution I've found that really works is to use a PDF library to write the formatted text to a PDF directly from PHP (or Python or another language, but you mentioned PHP and I've done that). I've used R&OS quite a bit:

http://pdf-php.sourceforge.net/

It may take a little while to get up to speed, but you can do pretty much anything with it, including easily create nicely formatted tables, flowing text and embedded images. The catch is that, with the exception of a few tags like <b></b> and <i></i> you don't get to use any HTML or CSS - essentially you write two output routines, one for HTML and one for PDF.